# List all Emacs variables containing regexp

Tags: variables, emacs, elisp

How do I find all variables containing "directory" in their name in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-x apropos-variable RET directory`

Comment: But take note of the effect of a prefix argument on this function. See `C-h f apropos-variable` and `C-h f user-variable-p` (the latter being the predicate a variable needs to match in order to be displayed by default).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to find all variables containing a string, check out the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229992/596361) answer. Here i created the list of pairs in the form `(<variable> . <value>)`.

## Explanation of functions used

- [`mapatoms`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#Creating-Symbols) is a map-style function to operate on `obarray`, variable that contains all symbols used by Emacs.
- [`prin1-to-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html#Output-Functions) returns a string with the printed representation of an object.
- [`string-match`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) finds a regexp in a string, returns index or nil if not found.
- [`push`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#List-Variables) inserts element into a head of a list in-place.
- [`remove-if`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Sequence-Functions.html#index-remove_002dif-115) is equivalent to inverted [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29)
- [`mapcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#Mapping-Functions) is an ordinary [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) function
- [`boundp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html#Void-Variables) returns t if variable's value is not void.
- [`symbol-value`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html#Accessing-Variables) returns value of a variable.

## Final code

```
(let ((matching-variables
       (let ((result '()))
         ;; result will contain only variables containing "directory"
         (mapatoms (lambda (variable)
                     (let* ((variable-string (prin1-to-string variable))
                            (match (string-match "directory" variable-string)))
                       (if match
                           (push variable result)))))
         result)))
  ;; returns list of pairs (variable-name . variable-value)
  (remove-if #'null
             (mapcar (lambda (variable)
                       (if (boundp variable)
                           (cons variable (symbol-value variable))
                         nil))
                     matching-variables)))
```

## References

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031385/596361